# Zend Framework 2: How to properly replace Figlet with reCaptcha on zfcUser

Tags: zend-framework2, recaptcha, zfcuser

I am trying to replace Figlet with reCaptcha on a zfcUser registration form. Partial instruction on how to accomplish this can be found on https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser#changing-registration-captcha-element but no complete instruction exists.

Checking the README.md file has a two-step instruction on how to accomplish this but still the CAPTCHA uses Figlet when rendered on the form.

Has anyone successfully implemented this? I really need a hand on this one.

Thanks in advance.

---

### EDIT: Here is a proven working solution I developed:

**1. Add to composer.json**

```
// Add the lines below under the "require" element:
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zendframework": ">2.2.0rc1",
        "zendframework/zendservice-recaptcha": "2.*"
```

}

**2. Goto to your project's ZF2 installation directory and execute this command:**

```
php composer.phar update
```

**3. Replace or Create config/autoload/database.global.php with:**

```
<?php
$config = array(
    'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
    'dbhost' => 'localhost',
    'dbport' => '3306',
    'dbname' => 'CHANGEME',
    'dbuser' => 'CHANGEME',
    'dbpass' => 'CHANGEME',
);

return array(
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
    'db' => array(
        'driver'    => 'pdo',
        'dsn'       => 'mysql:dbname='.$config['dbname'].';host='.$config['dbhost'],
        'username'  => $config['dbuser'],
        'password'  => $config['dbpass'],
    ),
);
```

**4: Execute this on your mySQL server:**

```
CREATE TABLE `user`
(
    `user_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `username` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL UNIQUE,
    `email` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL UNIQUE,
    `display_name` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    `password` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    `state` SMALLINT UNSIGNED
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET="utf8";
```

**5. Create/Replace config/autoload/recaptcha.global.php with:**

```
<?php
define('RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY','CHANGEME');
define('RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY','CHANGEME');

return array(
    'zfcuser' => array(
        'form_captcha_options' => array(
            'class'   => 'Zend\Captcha\ReCaptcha',
            'options' => array(
                'privkey' => RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY,
                'pubkey'  => RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY,
            ),
        ),
    ),

    'di'=> array(
        'instance'=>array(
            'alias'=>array(
                'recaptcha_element' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Captcha',
            ),

            'ZfcUser\Form\Register' => array(
                'parameters' => array(
                    'captcha_element'=>'recaptcha_element',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

**6. Create/Replace config/autoload/zfcuser.global.php with:**

```
<?php
$settings = array(    
    'enable_registration' => true,
    'enable_username' => true,
    'auth_adapters' => array( 100 => 'ZfcUser\Authentication\Adapter\Db' ),
    'enable_display_name' => false,
    'auth_identity_fields' => array( 'email' ),
    'use_registration_form_captcha' => true,
    'user_login_widget_view_template' => 'zfc-user/user/login.phtml',
);


return array(
    'zfcuser' => $settings,
    'service_manager' => array(
        'aliases' => array(
            'zfcuser_zend_db_adapter' => (isset($settings['zend_db_adapter'])) ? $settings['zend_db_adapter']: 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter',
        ),
    ),
);
```

**7. Navigate to http://yourdomain.com/user**

**8. Enjoy! :)**

Comment: Hi will you explain how to use this function in form and controller

Comment: You don't need to do anything in the controller. Just follow the solution I posted and it's all done. The login and registration forms are already done for you. To access the login form, just navigate to http://yourdomain.com/user or whatever domain you are using.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help as much as I can. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I did it, it might not be the best or correct way but it worked for me:

Add the recaptcha service to your `composer.json` file:

```php
"require": {
    "Zendframework/zendservice-recaptcha": "2.*"
}
```

Run composer to get the service. Then you need to specify the ReCaptcha config.
I created a separate config file to store the ReCaptcha keys:

```php
//zfcuser.local.php
return array(
    'zfcuser' => array(
        'form_captcha_options' => array(
            'options' => array(
                'privkey' => RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY,   
                'pubkey'  => RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY,
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Then `ZfcUser` captcha config looks like so, telling it to use the ReCaptcha service:

```php
//zfcuser.global.php
'form_captcha_options' => array(
    'class'   => 'Zend\Captcha\ReCaptcha',
    'options' => array(
        'wordLen'    => 6,
        'expiration' => 300,
        'timeout'    => 300,
     ),
),
```

**Edit:**

You don't need the `recaptcha.global.php`. You can call the config file whatever you like aslong as it ends with .global.php or .local.php. You usually name things `.local.php` when you don't want them in version control.

In this case I named the file zfcuser.local.php because all it does is store the ReCaptcha keys and I didn't want them in version control.

All the config files get merged in to one array when the application is started. So basically, ignore the `ZfcUser` documentation. Or maybe someone else can explain how to get it working that way.

The third block of code is the zfcuser.global.php.

Comment: Hi. Just some clarifications:
1. What about the changes to the recaptcha.global.php and zfuser.global.php as specified in the official documentation? Should I keep them?

2. What file should I put the third block of code you provided?

Comment: Thanks. I made mine work by inheriting the original class from /vendor and doing the mods there and by adding the options to zfcuser.global.php and recaptcha.global.php. Anyway, I'm awarding the point to you. Good job!